# How can I tell Express to manage pdf files?

Tags: reactjs, express, server-side-rendering, node.js-fs

I want to make my react App SEO-friendly, and to do this I want to implement a **SSR with express.**

So I added a **server** folder in my projects with both files (**server.js** and **index.js**) :

**server.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';

import App from '../src/App';

const app = express();

app.use('^/$', (req, res, next) => {

    fs.readFile(path.resolve('./build/index.html'), 'utf-8', (err,data) => {
        console.log(err, data)
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(500).send("Some error happened");
        }
        return res.send(
            data.replace(
                '<div id="root"></div>', 
                `<div id="root">${ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />)}</div>`
                )
            )
    });
    
});

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build')));

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on 3000')
})
```

**index.js**

```
require('ignore-styles');

require('@babel/register')({
    ignore: [/(node_module)/],
    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
})

require('./server')
```

In my project, I have some pdf files, because I implemented a pdf reader.

When I launch the command `node server/index.js`, I got this problem :

[image]

How is it possible to make this working, keeping my pdf files in the project ?

Thank you